# If command malfunction "Name SRC_Path & fname As DEST_Path & fname"

Tags: vba

Unsure what has happened over the weekend but my code no longer works and I am receiving an error message for the below code. "Name SRC_Path & fname As DEST_Path & fname" any help is greatly appreciated kind regards

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    
    Dim SRC_Path As String
    SRC_Path = "C:\Users\oliver\OneDrive\Client Files\Job Sheets\"
       If ComboBox1.Value = Sheet1.Range("A115") Then
    Dim DEST_Path As Variant
    DEST_Path = "C:\Users\oliver\OneDrive\Client Files\Wasdell Packaging Cleanrooms\Job Sheets\"
    Dim fname As Variant
        
    fname = Dir(SRC_Path & "*Wasdell Packaging Cleanrooms*")
    If Len(fname) > 0 Then
        Name SRC_Path & fname As DEST_Path & fname
    End If
End If
```

Comment: What error message do you receive? Do both folders exists?

Comment: Hi yes both folders exist I receive runtime error 53

Comment: You have checked the values of the different strings? Does a file with `fname` exists in the destination folder? Is the to be moved file opened?